# BeautifulSoup findAll HTML class with multiple variable class inputs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, args

I have the following code which scrapes a website for divs with the class "odd" or "even". I'd like to make "odd" and "even" an argument my function takes in, which would allow me to add other divs as well. Here is my code:

```
#
# Imports
#

import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
from pprint import pprint

#
# library
#

def get_soup(url):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    contents = page.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
    body = soup.findAll("tr", ["even", "odd"])
    string_list = str([i for i in body])
    return string_list


def save_to_file(path, soup):
    with open(path, 'w') as fhandle:
        fhandle.write(soup)


#
# script
#

def main():
    url = r'URL GOES HERE'
    path = os.path.join('PATH GOES HERE')
    the_soup = get_soup(url)
    save_to_file(path, the_soup)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'd like to incorporate `*args` into the code so the `get_soup function` would look like this:

```
def get_soup(url, *args):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    contents = page.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
    body = soup.findAll("tr", [args])
    string_list = str([i for i in body])
    return string_list

def main():
    url = r'URL GOES HERE'
    path = os.path.join('PATH GOES HERE')
    the_soup = get_soup(url, "odd", "even")
    save_to_file(path, the_soup)
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. Ideas?

Comment: Do you have the URL for your test site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put *args* in a list, *args* is already a *tuple* so just pass that:

```
body = soup.findAll("tr", args)
```

If you `[args]`, you would end up with something like `[("odd","even")]`.

Also `str([i for i in body])` makes no real sense, it would be the same as just doing `str(body)` but I don't see how that format could be useful.

Comment: This is perfect! As for the str([i for i in body]) - this was a combination of two functions that I hadnt cleaned up yet. I evidently copied the wrong function - though it did the same thing as what my other one did. Thanks @Padraic Cunningham!